# When I download a zip from github, what is the hex string at the end of the file name represent?

Tags: git, github

If I go to https://github.com/wesm/pandas and click the "Download" button to download a zip (or tar) archive of the repository, the file name of the archive I get is:

```
wesm-pandas-0.3.0-93-g1d40e65.zip
```

I can see that `wesm-pandas` represents the project name, and `0.3.0` represents the project version.

Does `93` represent the number of commits on that branch?

What does `g1d40e65` represent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the username and the project, the filename is obtained from the output of:

```
git describe --always
```

Example from the man page:

> [torvalds@g5 git]$ git describe parent
>
> v1.0.4-14-g2414721
>
> i.e. the current head of my "parent"
>   branch is based on v1.0.4, but since
>   it has a few commits on top of that,
>   describe has added the number of
>   additional commits ("14") and an
>   abbreviated object name for the commit
>   itself ("2414721") at the end.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html

So in your case, 93 is the number of commits since 0.3.0 and the hex after g is the sha1 of the latest commit

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/blog/651-annotated-downloads for details on the filename format: the `1d40e65` represents an SHA of the last commit on that branch, and the 93 is the number of commits since the latest tag.