# GitHub Api download zip or tarball link

Tags: git, github, github-api

There was a good link here about how the zip/tarball string is created

[When I download a zip from github, what is the hex string at the end of the file name represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334040/when-i-download-a-zip-from-github-what-is-the-hex-string-at-the-end-of-the-file)

But I'm looking at the GitHub APIv3 and I was curious if I'm missing something.

1. Is there a way to get the zip/tarball link via an API call?
2. If not, is there a way I can build that string without using the git binary or library? Meaning, can I use various API calls to pull out th data a need and assemble to URL I need?

I know the second question is a little unreasonable for stackoverflow and this is a bit of a fun project for me, so I would prefer on the second question if you just kind of nudged me in the right direction as opposed to throwing down a code snippet. Or just told me if it was possible.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can `wget` your way out of the GitHub repo to get a tar file ([archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051803/git-archive-vs-cp)):

```bash
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/User/repo/archive/master.tar.gz

# better, if the certificate authorities are present:
wget https://github.com/User/repo/archive/master.tar.gz
```

will get you a file named 'master' from the user 'User''s repo 'repo'.

The [updated V3 API url](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-tar) is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/User/repo/:archive_format/:ref
#
# two possibilities for fomat:
https://api.github.com/repos/User/repo/tarball/master
https://api.github.com/repos/User/repo/zipball/master

# from github example:
$curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/tarball > octokit.tar.gz
```

You can then `tar xpvf master`, getting the full archive. It will create a directory following the naming convention described in the [question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334040/when-i-download-a-zip-from-github-what-is-the-hex-string-at-the-end-of-the-file).

No Git binary is needed to get an archive from GitHub, thanks to their [download service "Nodeload"](https://github.com/blog/678-meet-nodeload-the-new-download-server).

---

[`ligemer`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085469/ligemer) proposed [in an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13466031) the following example:

**Edit 2016-08-25 - Shell Example With Wget, Variables, and Untar:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -ex

# arguments:
# token = $1
# organization = $2
# repo name = $3
# branch = $4

wget --header="Authorization: token ${1}" --header="Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -O - https://api.github.com/repos/${2}/${3}/tarball/${4} | tar xz
```

Call via:

```bash
$ scriptName.sh token my-organization site.example master
```

The command above will download and extract the GitHub folder to the same directory as the script.

---

[Diogo Quintela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248833/diogo-quintela) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377081/github-api-download-zip-or-tarball-link/8378458#comment67958619_8378458):

> The following example allow the download, extract and cut the top level directory

```bash
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/tarball | tar xz --strip=1
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently getting it that way via curl. I was just curious if there was a way to get the download link through the API. I know it isn't specifically useful as much as it's my own curiosity.

Comment: @Mike: no API that I know of is needed to get an archive from GitHub. The point is to propose a direct link for you to use.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I think I'll mark the answer and move on. Thank you both for your advice. I appreciate it.

Comment: What if repository is private? Anyway to get the zipball in this case?

Comment: @jayarjo good question. I am not sure (unless you are the owner of that repo).

Comment: I am, but I need to request download link from the script. It probably needs to be authorized somehow.

Comment: Not work now,i try your command just get the mast file,do not get tarball file

Comment: @janwen you always get a file named '`master`'. But try a '`tar xpvf master`, and you will see: it works! That '`master`' file is actually a tarball.

Comment: @janwen see an example at the very beginning of: https://raw.github.com/VonC/compileEverything/master/.cpl/doc. This is how I download my project tarball.

Comment: Thank you @Ligemer for the example.

Comment: The following example allow the download, extract and cut the top level directory `curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/tarball | tar xz --strip=1`

Comment: @DiogoQuintela Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: For public repos, without api.github.com, does it not have a access limit? (cause I'm having none. its wierd.. for this expensive operation)

Comment: @softmarshmallow I am sure there must be some kind of limit, but I don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 31):

The syntax is described [in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-tar):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

The following example URL will point (via a [302 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)) to a zip archive of `master` in the [hadley/devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) repo:

[`https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/devtools/zipball/master`](https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/devtools/zipball/master)

(The other option for `archive_format` is `tarball`.)

I have no idea since when this API is available.

Comment: Hey, is there any way to download just one folder? like only the `R` folder in your example.

Comment: @samaYo: I'm not aware of a way to achieve this via the API, but you might want to try [`git archive --remote=... <tree-ish> <path>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive). I'd be interested to know if this works with GitHub ;-)

Comment: @samayo Alternativ way is to untar the folder you need

Here is an example I am using when downloading a github archive where I only wish src folder

tar -xzf archive.tar.gz "$(tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | head -1 )src" --strip 1

Comment: Updated Github documentation link: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-zip

Comment: @samayo Were you able to figure out a way to download one of the subfolder in the repo? 
The tarball API does not support the path.

Comment: @PraveenMak I don't know if I can remember well as this was a long time ago. But I would say no. I didn't find the solution I think. Maybe it's better if you ask a question on it. Good luck