# Print entire github repository

Tags: github, printing

Is it possible to print(out of a printer) an entire github repository quickly? I have a repository with a large amount of code files that would take an excessively long time to download and print off manually. The order in which the files are printed does not matter(so long as each file is structurally together). I have found tools such as gitprint, however only support one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you cannot **[download the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378458/6309)**, instead of cloning the repository with all its history.

That way, you only get the last state of master HEAD, which should be much smaller than the all repository.
It would then be much easier to list all files and script a command printing them all from your local disk.